# How to change output of graph title from a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop

I have this for loop in python

```
for i in range(len(population_data["State"])):
     list = (population_data["State"][i])
```

which prints the list of states

```
AK
AL
AR
AZ
.
.
.
WY
```

I am creating multiple graphs, and I need the title on each graph to be a different state.

For example, graph 1 should be labeled AK, and graph 2 should be labeled AL and so on.

I'm thinking a for loop would work, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Since you will loop all the population data and create each graph separately, I think you can directly assign the title of each graph by using "population_data["State"][i]".

Answer (score 0):

its simple

```
for i in list:
   plt.title("%s" %i)
```

Comment: hi just updated the question if you can answer that!

Comment: `plt.title("%s" %list )`

Comment: Observation: This is old syntax.  Consider updating to `plt.title("{}".format(list))` or better yet (for Py3.6+) `plt.title(f"{list}")`.  I’d be remiss to not mention the`list` variable is overwriting the builtin, so should be changed.